# Button is not enabled with ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<button ng-click="Event.Methods.Submit()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="IsDisabled">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
 $scope.IsDisabled = true;
```

I need to disable the submit button when press it and enable it again if there has been any error. It works fine with button press, but it's not working on other scenario even though I have set it as  `$scope.IsDisabled = false;`. But when I change anything on the page (e.g. text box value) then it enables. Can you tell me why? I have checked the value of `IsDisabled` when there is an error: `IsDisabled` is `false`, but the button still is not enabled. Why?

**Good Reference about the :** **[$scope.$evalAsync()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm)**

Comment: The scenario is not quite clear, at least to me. Can you reproduce in fiddle ?

Comment: @OmriAharon Scenario is I have a submit button.When press it needs to be disable.It's working fine.But I need to enable the submit button if there will have any error on Ajax request.That part is not working even though the `$scope.IsDisabled` value is `false` ?

Comment: Seems like it's waiting for another digest cycle. Try wrapping the part where you reanable it like this: `$scope.$evalAsync(function () { $scope.IsDisabled = false; });`

Comment: @naeramarth7 It gives this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` ?

Comment: try to write it like this: `$scope.IsDisabled = false; $scope.$apply(); `

Comment: @naeramarth7 It's working.Can you put it as an answer.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hmm... I've never have to do that until now.  This sample kind of simulate both success and failure scenario as you can see in there, it has never failed to enable / disable the button after the service call... http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/8urqxgv4/

Comment: @JimmyChandra Yes,I also used it without `$evalAsync` on number of places on my project and it works fine.But on this specific scenario where it didn't work until use the `$evalAsync`.it's really strange :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating data after an AJAX reques in this case needs to trigger an digest cycle manually - can't tell why, since I don't know the whole code, but this might do the job:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
  $scope.IsDisabled = false;
});
```

Avoid using `$scope.$apply();` when ever possible, since you might run into an `Error: $digest already in progress`.